# Delphi 7 / Archive pdf files on server caused error

Tags: file, delphi, pdf-generation, delphi-7, archive

I have some problems with delphi 7 and generating a pdf file out of word and archive the file on a server.

Description:
I have a word-doc (5-40 sites). 
To generate a pdf-file I send the doc to a pdf-docu-com-printer. After generating the pdf-file, the file will archived on a server.

My problem is: the archive function try to archive the pdf file, although the file is not rdy.... In most cases I got an error.

I have to wait, till the PDF-file is finished, but how?

I can't install any application or tools or something else...

Thx.

Comment: As we have no idea what code you're using to print, and no idea what code you're using to generate or archive the PDF, it's impossible to answer this question. See [ask], and [edit] to provide the details.

Comment: Duplicate ? [delphi check whether file is in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502996/delphi-check-whether-file-is-in-use)